# JSON List of Objects to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class User :

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}

    public Integer getAge(){return age;}
    public void setAge(Integer age){this.age = age;}
}
```

What I want to be able to do is take a string in json format (which is a list of User objects) .... parse it and wind up with an ArrayList

I have gotten as far as this:

```
String json = "[{"name":"bill","age":12},{"name":"bob","age":20}];
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayList<User> userList = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
```

The problem of course is that the mapper wants to map directly to a User object not a List of user objects. I feel like there is something simple im missing here.... what is it ??

Comment: So instead of mapping to a `User`, why don't you map to a `ArrayList<User>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<User> list2 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, User.class));
```

If we want to create concrete JavaType instances then Jackon provides TypeFactory (note for version >= 1.8 usage should be done using ObjectMapper, more details [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/TypeFactory.html)  ). The TypeFactory class provides various helper methods like mapType, collectionType, etc.

Comment: some explanations would definitely improve the response!

Comment: this is the one that i went with and its doing what i want it to do. As a follow up question if you had the json as i listed above and ech user object also had an attribute List<Address> how would that factor into this solution

Comment: @Deslyxia you can achieve this by writing custom Deserializer i.e. MyDeser extends StdDeserializer<T>

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User[] navigationArray = gson.fromJson(json, User[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(navigationArray));
```

Or this way

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
System.out.println(userList);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Jackson ObjectMapper, you can have:

```
String json = "[{\"name\":\"bill\",\"age\":12},{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":20}]";
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<User> userList = mapper.readValue(json,ArrayList.class);
                System.out.println(userList);
```

prints:

```
[{name=bill, age=12}, {name=bob, age=20}]
```